# create Schema and retrieve mongoose nested objects array values

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Actually my aim is to find the total time spent in each category for example in solution

or Billing category, please provide me a solution, I am new to mongoose so I

don't know the correct way to achieve this (is it possible to use MapandReduce method?).

Thanks in Advance.

```
    userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        type: String,
        timesheet: {
            created: {
                type: Date
            },
            categories: [{
                catname: String,
                cusname: String,
                hours: Number
            }]

        }
    });
    var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

    module.exports = function (app) {

        var usr = {
            username: "Ardrew",
            type: "Billing",
            timesheet: {
                created: new Date('2014-06-04'),
                categories: [{
                    catname: "Solution",
                    cusname: "IBM",
                    hours: 8
                }, {
                    catname: "Solution",
                    cusname: "AT&T",
                    hours: 4
                }, {
                    catname: "Sales",
                    cusname: "AT&T",
                    hours: 4
                }]
            }
        }

        var user = new User(usr);      

        user.save(function (err, user) {


        });


        /*  User.find({"timesheet.categories.catname":"Solution"},function(err,result){
                   console.log(result)
          }*/
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Model.find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) queries the collection for documents that match the criteria provided in the first argument. For example:

```
User.find({type: 'Sales'}, function (err, docs) { })
```

This example query will find all the documents where `type` is `Sales`. The callback receives a cursor that you can iterate.

But in your case it's not even needed to call `find`. [`Model#save`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) returns the document in the callback, so you can access the field like this:

```
user.save(function(err, user) {
   console.log(user.timesheet.categories);
});
```

Comment: When I tried to console the result it was undefined, that is the problem. How can I get the values of categories using find method. console.log(user.timesheet.categories);-->undefined

Comment: @user3737613 This code should work, you really don't need to use find. Can you try to add `console.log(err)` to check if there was an error? Also, what's the value of `user` inside the callback? Can you also add `console.log(user)`?

Comment: Its working! Thanks for your valuable time. My need is to calculate total no of hours spent by Sales category. Please help me out in this!

Comment: @user3737613 Please ask a new question, it's hard to answer this in a comment.

Comment: Yeah Sure, I will create a new question